# NIntegration[?] and N[Integration[?]]

Tags: numerical-integration

The following Integral answer is different with the following two methods. which one is correct?

```
a = 10^-6;
t = 10000;
N[Integrate[E^(-w/a) (Sin[w t]/w), {w, 0, 1}]]

Out= 0.00999967 + 0. I

NIntegrate[E^(-w/a) (Sin[w t]/w), {w, 0, 1},
MaxRecursion -> 300, AccuracyGoal -> 10 ]

Out=0.
```

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at `With[{a = 1*^-6, t = 1*^4}, {N[Integrate[E^(-w/a) (Sin[w t]/w), {w, 0, 1}]], NIntegrate[E^(-w/a) (Sin[w t]/w), {w, 0, 1}, Method -> "LevinRule"]}]`